# IE cannot download files over SSL served by WebSphere

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, websphere, download

IE 7 & 8 both throw an error when users attempt to download a csv file over https.

> Internet Explorer cannot download downloadPage.jsf. Internet Explorer was not able to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again

I read about the issues IE has in relation to caching so I changed the response to allow public caching. See this issue: [IE cannot download foo.jsf. IE was not able to open this internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034454/internet-explorer-cannot-download-the-file-served-by-jsf)

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
```

But I am still getting this error.

Any ideas what else could be causing the issue? Here's the complete snippet:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + browserFilename + "\"");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response.getOutputStream().write(contentBytes);
context.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Works over normal http though?

Comment: I'm not sure at the moment, having problems with the application on non-ssl mode.

Comment: This post helped me out so much. Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that WebSphere automatically adds `Cache-Control:no-cache=set-cookie` response header when cookies are included in the response. IE8 & older do not like this when downloading over SSL.

There are two possible fixes as per this [IBM Developerworks forum thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=28910):

1. Add the custom response header `CookiesConfigureNoCache:false` for HTTP transport Channel in WebSphere (it's true by default).

   ```
   response.setHeader("CookiesConfigureNoCache", "false");
   ```
2. Explicitly set the `Cache-Control` header **after** cookies are being added, this will override the WebSphere-set one.

   ```
   response.addCookie(...);
   response.addCookie(...);
   ...
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", ...);
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by  Set the 'Cache-Control' header after all cookie processing is complete? How do I know all cookie processing is over? Can I do it in servlet?

Comment: @webdev - Yes, at the servlet level.

Comment: m sorry not sure how do I know cookie processing is over?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with IE8.
I made small changes to my code.

Response.ClearHeaders();  //needed, otherwise "no-cache: set-cookie" was there, had to get rid of it

Response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private");

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same issue when the app server was configured to use SSL.  The trick for me to get it working after the https was turned on:

```
   string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + rptName + ".xls" + "";    

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=1");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for you post. I changed my file download logic to match yours and it now works for the IE8 client that was having an issue. I'm not sure exactly what line/lines of code made the difference, but anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with caching:

This knowledge base article may help you, 
[Internet Explorer is unable to open Office documents from an SSL Web site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431)

Mentioned in this Stack Overflow question: [Cannot open xls file in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070820/cannot-open-xls-file-in-ie)

Comment: Still no luck. I've tried all sorts of combinations in the response header. It is working fine in a previous version of the application. The only diffenrce is the presence of 2 Set-Cookie items in the response as well as 'Cache-Control: no-cache=set-cookie'. Could this no-cache=set-cookie value be causing problems?

Comment: I wasn't sure on "Cache-Control: no-cache=set-cookie". But looking at http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2007Mar/internet-cookies/ (the section titled: Do cookies also get stored in caches?) I don't think it should cause any problems. Could it be to do with custom security settings in IE? Are you running IE on a corporate network with extra restrictions (perhaps try firefox)?

Comment: Yes it's on a corporate network but works fine in firefox and Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Also, it's happening for multiple users on the network so wouldnt be any custom IE setting we made ourselves.

Comment: @Thomas Buckley interesting are you running behind a proxy server?

Comment: Here is another link which may prove useful (but it pretty much covers the same stuff as the link above): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and help Alex. It turned out to be a websphere issue...see my added answer.

Comment: @Thomas Buckley: Glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem.
After set "Content-Disposition" and "Content-Type", add this code.

Java code

```
// IE requires these three lines, exactly like this
response.setHeader("CookiesConfigureNoCache", "false");             
response.setHeader("Pragma","private,no-cache");     
response.setHeader("Cache-control","private,no-store,no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate");
```

PHP code

```
// IE requires these three lines, exactly like this
header("CookiesConfigureNoCache: false");
header("Pragma: private,no-cache");
header("Cache-control: private,no-store,no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've done in my PHP code:

```
header( "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" );
header( "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$path" );
header( "Content-Type: attachment; application/pdf" );
header( "Content-Length: $info[7]" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache" );          // IE 8 requires these two lines, exactly like this
header( "Pragma: private" );                            // IE 8 requires these two lines, exactly like this
readfile( $tmpfile );
```