# IE7 & IE8, JSESSIONID cookie breaks file download

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, websphere, download

Is there a way to prevent websphere from sending cookies in a response on a per request/url basis?

Our users get a link which allows them to download a file. Works fine in all major browsers except for IE8 & IE7. In IE7 & IE8, the file download breaks when cookies are sent with the response.

When a new session is created, the WebSphere sends a JSESSIONID cookie, and sets Cache-control to *no-cache=set-cookie*. This causes the download process to break in IE8 and lower.

Things I tried:

1) I know that *no-cache=set-cookie* can be turned off in Websphere admin console, but it's not an option.

2) The websphere is fronted by a web server, so the response headers can be changed using the web server, but it's not really an option.

3) I created a servlet filter, but it seems like whatever websphere does happens after the filter runs.

4) I created a JSP page that would prompt file download on load. The idea was that the cookie will be exchanged on page load, so that it won't interfere with the download. Unfortunately, because the download is triggered through JavaScript, IE blocks the download, and a user needs to manually approve it.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has bug that may connected with your problem. [Bug description.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308/en-us) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573524/ie-not-downloading-files-over-ssl)

I solved similar problem using [good article](http://markarlenplace.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/websphere-and-internet-explorer-a-tale-of-blocked-downloads/).

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, the link is sent over email, and it's the first point of contact with the web server. When clicked, a new session is created, and a JSESSIONID cookie is sent back in the response. I don't set any cookies myself. I tried changing the response headers using a filter, but it didn't work - see my #3. Good article though.