# IE 8 does not download files

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing the issue as mentioned in: [ie-not-downloading-files-over-ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573524/ie-not-downloading-files-over-ssl/%22ie-not-downloading-files-over-ssl%22)

The problem occurs if the server is using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and has added one or both of the following HTTP headers to the response message:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate
```

But it is a solution to [Disable back button in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application)

I am looking for a solution which enables file download on IE 8 & also disables back button.

Comment: Are you using any third party libs to implement `file Download` and is this site on internet or Intranet.Cause `IE8` behaves differently in Intranet

Comment: Intranet. No, I am using primefaces' file download.