# Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined. error for IE (Asp.net Website)

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, cross-browser

[image]

WHen I try to download from Chrome it works fine, but in IE 8 it is not downloading it is showing the error above,

```
    protected void btn_ExcelDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid_UserTable.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    string subject = lbl_Subj.Text;
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + subject + "-Status.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    Grid_UserTable.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    rptList.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());     
    Response.End();
}
```

When I used developer tool in chrome it gave Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined. error but downloaded the file, but IE is throwing the error shown in the image, what should i do, thanks.

I am able to download the file in IE8 when I run the website using Visual studio, but when I try to download it from the website which is uploaded in server I am getting the above error,, The error is only in IE 8.

I tried changing the IE browser Compatibility mode on  and off, even then I receive same error.

This is my head content

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me in IE8. Which version of IE that you are using?

Comment: It works in local host, when uploaded in server it gives the above error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133776/ie8-wont-download-a-file-with-a-custom-mime-type-with-uac-enabled   same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Solved by removing this line from the code.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");
```

[Source link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx)

Comment: try by enabling the buffer `Response.Buffer = true;` Also, try `application/vnd.ms-excel`